# How to retrieve the value of switch and pass into Object?

Tags: swift, uiswitch, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to get the value of a switch and pass it to an object in a view controller.

Below is the code of my view controller. I have created a label, switch outlet, and switch action.

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstTimeConducting: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var firstTime_Conduct: UISwitch!

@IBAction func firstTimeConductSwitchTap(_ sender: Any) {
    firstTimeConductTapped()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    firstTimeConductTapped()
}

func firstTimeConductTapped() {
    if firstTime_Conduct.isOn {
        value = "Yes"
    } else {
        value = "No"
    }
}
```

I have debugged it and it enters and gets the value as "yes" when I click on the switch from off to on state in simulator.

Then after returning to function `firstTimeConductSwitchTap()`, it  crashes saying the following error

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[app.RequestFormViewController first_TimeConduct:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb900421fc0'

I am just retrieving the value of "`value`" variable and passing it to object to display.

Can you suggest whether I am following the correct procedure and why I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear:

In Interface Builder there is a dead connection to a selector `first_TimeConduct`. Most likely you renamed the action method.

Search for `first_TimeConduct` with <kbd>⇧⌘F</kbd> and delete the connection.